# Angular momentum quantum number $l$ either integer or half integer

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, representation-theory, spin-statistics

I am trying to understand why the angular momentum quantum number $l$ can **either** be an integer **or** an half-integer. At least this is stated in the book that I am learning from. It is the [book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-71933-5) by Schwabl. In Chapter 5 the eigenvalues of $L^2$ and $L_z$ are derived using the algebraic approach with commutator relations.

The result is that the eigenvalues of $L^2$ are given by: $$\lambda_l = \hbar^2l(l+1)\tag{1}$$ In the last sentence in the derivation Schwabl states that

> The angular momentum eigenvalues $l$ are either integral or half integral, and the eigenvalues $m$ range in integer steps from $l$ to $-l$.

I understand the proof, i.e. that we have the step operators $L_+$ and $L_-$ and we use them to show that it takes $k\in \mathbb{N}_0$ steps to step down (using $L_-$) from the highest possible ladder rung to the lowest one. So we need $k$ steps to go from $l$ (highest rung) to $-l$ (lowest rung), such that $l-k=-l$, from which it follows that $l=\frac{k}{2}.$

From $l=\frac{k}{2}$ with $k\in\mathbb{N}_0$ I would conclude that the spectrum of $L^2$ is given by:

$$\sigma_{L^2}=\left\{\hbar^2l(l+1)\;\middle|\; l=0,\frac{1}{2},1,\frac{3}{2},2,\frac{5}{2},3,...\right\}\tag{2}$$

However what Schwabl states is that the spectrum is **either** $$\sigma_{L^2}=\left\{\hbar^2l(l+1)\;\middle|\; l=0,1,2,3,...\right\}\tag{3}$$
**or** $$\sigma_{L^2}=\left\{\hbar^2l(l+1)\;\middle|\; l=\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2},\frac{5}{2},...\right\}\tag{4}$$

I also have other books (like Griffiths) where the word *either* is not used in the explanation. So my question is if using *either* is correct or not. And if yes, how can I see this?

Comment: A natural number *k* is either even or odd. In the first case, *l* is integer, and in the second, half integer. The possible eigenvalues are a *set* containing integers and half integers. What is this weirdo "sequence" stuff?

Comment: Different *l* s characterize different representations and don't "talk" to each other, unless you have cooked up spectrum generating operators, highly unlikely in an introductory context.

Comment: Thank you Cosmas Zachos, I updated the question using spectra of $L^2$. Regarding your second comment, does this mean that without additional knowledge the spectrum should be the one given in equation (2) in my question?

Comment: Yes, of course the spectrum is in (2). It is a *set* textbooks ponderously illustrate by (2). You might treat all spins in subsets (3) and (4)  differently, when you learn about bosons and fermions, but, as far as these arguments go, I have no clue why you are insisting on that "either". Of course *l* can be either an integer, or a half integer: it can't be both! You seem to suspect there is something deeper or systematic in the conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

$K$ can be an odd or an even number. In the first case the sequence is of half integers. For example: if $k = 1$, the values for $m$ are $-\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{2}$.

In the second case, there is a sequence of integers. For example: if $k = 2$, the values for $m$ are $-1, 0, 1$.

There is no $k$ that leads to a complete sequence of half integers and integers.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I think my question is not precise enough. I think you confused the quantum number $l$ with the quantum number $m$. The $l$ is non negative and $m$ can take values in $m = -l, -l+1,-l+2,...,l-2,l-1,l$. So for $m$ your answer indeed is correct. However the question is why for all $l$'s there should only be either even or odd $k$'s. Because in all derivations I found the proof starts with fixing $\lambda_l$. Then for this paricular $\lambda_l$ a $k$ value of $k_l$ is found. To my understanding for different $l$'s we have different $k_l$'s. I will update my question later

Comment: You are right. I corrected my answer. Anyway, $l$ can be theoretically any integer or half integer. But the sequence of $m$ in each case is: or only integers or only half integers.

Comment: So would you say that the books claim of $l$ being either integer or half-integer is wrong? (the emphasis here is on the word *either*)

Comment: Could be a translation issue? The author is not native English speaker.

Comment: Unfortunately not, he is german (as me) and in the german version of the book also the word *either* is there.